# Filter Formula in Google Sheet

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, google-analytics, datatables, filtering

I am using the below filter formula to filter by conditions.

But if cell A7 is blank I want to ignore the second condition which is `Database!D3:D=A7`.

```
=FILTER({'Database'!C3:F},'Database'!A3:A=R7,'Database!D3:D=A7
```

Filtering from another sheet on multiple conditions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a formula that can use for both cases :

```
=FILTER({'Database'!C3:F},
       ('Database'!A3:A = R7) * IF(A7 = "", 1, 'Database'!D3:D = A7))
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: If its working, mark the answer as accepted. so, it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Answer accepted